# How to use urls saved in a data base as source for source urls in casperjs using php?

Tags: php, casperjs

I have a small problem, i am new to casperjs so i was wondering if casper can work hand in hand with my current php script that loops through the results of of my database query results.

```
<?php
$urls = query url database

foreach($url as $url){
   then I send an execute command to casperjs.
}
?>
```

Then here is the js code where i want looped urls to be sent.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
viewportSize: {
    width: 1024,
    height: 768
}
});

casper.start(**URL from PHP HERE**, function() {
this.capture('shy.png', {
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: 1024,
    height: 1000
 });
});


casper.run();
```

my question is how do i send the command with a $url  as the url source value to casperjs?

I am trying to make screenshot for each url supplied.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the URL to casperjs process via shell commands:

[CasperJS CLI commands](http://casperjs.org/cli.html)

e.g. casperjs --crawlurl=http://example.com

Then, you can call the casperjs process from PHP with something like shell_exec:

[shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

Note that for normal server provider, they may block the use of shell_exec.

Comment: thank this seem to make a difference to me i will try it and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could just echo the urls in  tags with the php script.

```
<?php
$urls = do_query();
foreach($urls as $url){
    echo "<a href=\"$url\"">$url</a><br />;
}
?>
```

Inject jQuery with your casperjs. Then use casperjs evaluate() with a jQuery selector on all the links to return all the links again.

```
var links = this.evaluate( function() {

    var $ = jQuery; // map jQuery to $

    var links = [];

    $('a').each( function() {

        links.concat($(this).attr('href'));

    });

    return links;

});
```

Then loop through the links and capture them.

Good luck!